# How to get rid of overflow-error on AnimatedContainer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I implemented a MaterialBanner. I created a slide-up-effect once the user pushes the dismiss-button. Everything works ok, except for the overflow-error 'bottom overflowed by .. pixels', which appears when you click the dismiss button. The number of pixels in the error message counts down to zero as the bottom slides up. How can I solve this last issue? I expected the MaterialBanner to respect the maxHeight of the BoxConstraint instead of overflowing.

```
  AnimatedContainer buildAnimatedBanner(AuthViewModel vm) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: _heightBanner),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
      child: MaterialBanner(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        leading: Icon(EvilIcons.bell,
            size: 28, color: AppTheme.appTheme().colorScheme.onBackground),
        content: Text('Please check your inbox to verify email ${vm.email}'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "Send again",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppTheme.appTheme().colorScheme.onBackground),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text(
              "Dismiss",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: AppTheme.appTheme().colorScheme.onBackground),
            ),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => _heightBanner = 0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm thinking the purpose of the `AnimatedContainer` is to make a smooth transition when the height of the child (`MaterialBanner`) changes. You can use an [`AnimatedSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html) instead. It'll automatically handle the size change transitions for you and you don't have to worry about Overflow error.

Comment: I think this is the same problem as this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084415/animated-container-renderflex-overflowed-by-154-pixels-on-the-bottom

Answer (score 2):

It's overflowing because while the container is reducing in height, the content of the banner is still being rendered in full. You'll still see this error for as long as the material banner is still in view.

Looking at your code, I'm thinking the purpose of the `AnimatedContainer` is to make a smooth transition when the height of the child (`MaterialBanner`) changes.
You can use an [`AnimatedSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html) instead. It'll automatically handle the size change transitions for you and you don't have to worry about Overflow error.
It also provides an alignment param you can use to determine the direction of the transition. 
Below is a code. Demo can be found in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/akora-ingdkb/pen/ExVrMbZ).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyWidget createState() => MyWidget();
}

class MyWidget extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int itemCount = 2;
  bool pressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedSize(
          vsync: this,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            // height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemCount,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("$index"),
                );
              }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState((){
            itemCount = pressed ? 6 : 4;
            pressed = !pressed;
          });
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not get this to work. Could you show me how it would look in code?

Comment: I replaced the AnimatedContainer with the AnimatedSize as you suggested. Now the behaviour is not right in another way. When clicking Dismiss, now the banner is immediately invisible, and then the remaining content slides up. I made a codepen for this: https://codepen.io/leonvr/pen/OJydGWJ

Comment: It's overflowing because while the container is reducing in height, the content of the banner is still being rendered in full. You'll still see this error for as long as the material banner is still in view. It won't appear in a release build so that's no problem (if you don't mind).

Comment: I would like to have no errors. I think you missed my codepen. Could you take a look at that?

Comment: Yeah I did. The material banner has a fixed size. So it won't change even when your animated container is reducing in height. The error appears because while the container is reducing in size, the banner's height remain the same so flutter will tell you that the banner has overflowed.

Comment: I understand. But I was hoping there was a way to get around it

Comment: Not sure If there's an efficient workaround to avoid the overflow error

Comment: Thanks for trying. Maybe someone else knows how.