# Unable to remove overflow error while animation.(flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I write the code to AnimatedContainer and while it s expanding it give me gradual overflow but at full extent it s no more a overflow error. I tried the code on several screens and I don t have any problems. I want.

```
child: GestureDetector(
                                       onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            arr[index] = !arr[index];
                                            });
                                            },
                                child: Center(
                                 child:  AnimatedContainer(
                                    width: arr[index] ? 300.0 : 300.0,
                                    height: arr[index] ? 80.0 : 85.0+60.0*clase[index].clase,
                                    alignment:
                                    arr[index] ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional
                                      .center,
                                    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                                     child: arr[index] ? Inchis(index) :Deschis(index),//these are the classes
                            ),
                          ),
                              ),
```

Everything is fine but I want to escape of that little error.
Here is a video
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kreQN.jpg

Comment: The answer match with the answer on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084415/animated-container-renderflex-overflowed-by-154-pixels-on-the-bottom